# SQLAlchemy table property takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following SQLAlchemy class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))

    @property
    def encrypt_password(self, password):
        self.password = hash_password(password)
```

When I use the property I get the error `encrypt_password() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`.

```
user = db.session.query(User).filter_by(id=id).one()
user.encrypt_password('mypassword')
```

Why doesn't this work?  How do I implement a property for setting the password?

Comment: Remove the `@property` decorator. `encrypt_password` is a method, not a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the `getter` for the property as the `setter`.  Either remove the [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) because this is a function, or define the property correctly.

If you're going the property route, rename the `password` attribute and access it through the property for the getter.  Use a [`hybrid_property`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) so that the column is still queryable directly.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

_password = db.Column('password', db.String)

@hybrid_property
def password(self):
    return self._password

@password.setter
def password(self, value):
    self._password = hash_password(value)
```

```
user.password = 'stack overflow'  # gets hashed
user.password  # hashed value
session.query(User).filter(User.password.is_(None))  # query for users without passwords
```